# EntityFramework. SelectMany with Anonymous Type and Projection

Tags: entity-framework

I have a Banner with multiple Packs. Each pack has multiple files.

I have the following query:

```
  List<BannerModel> models = context.Banners
    .Select(x => x.Packs
      .SelectMany(p => p.Files, (p, f) => new {
        Id = p.Id,
        Flag = p.Flag,
        File = new { Id = f.Id, Flag = f.Flag, Key = f.Key, Mime = f.Mime }
      })
      .Where(a => a.File.Flag == "Img_200")
      .Select(a => new BannerModel { PackId = a.Id, ImageKey = a.File.Key })
    ).ToList();
```

1) I get the error on "ToList()".
   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

2) Then I removed the ToList and added "var models = ..."

I know there are 10 records where 5 of them satisfy the criteria:

```
.Where(a => a.File.Flag == "Img_200")
```

What is strange is that I get 10 items, 5 with data and 5 with no data.

Where I should only get a list of 5 items. The one that satisfy the criteria.

Could someone help me solving this problem?

Thank you,
Miguel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should this be:

```
List<BannerModel> models = context.Banners
    .SelectMany(x => x.Packs
        .SelectMany(p => p.Files, (p, f) => new {
            Id = p.Id,
            Flag = p.Flag,
            File = new { Id = f.Id, Flag = f.Flag, Key = f.Key, Mime = f.Mime }
        })
    .Where(a => a.File.Flag == "Img_200")
    .Select(a => new BannerModel { PackId = a.Id, ImageKey = a.File.Key })
    ).ToList();
```