# how to fetch data from two associated tables in entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-entities

I have two tables named Places and experiences having one to many relationship. I want to get data from these table in following format-

```
[
 {
"PlaceId": 1,
"PlaceName": "Agra",
"Experience": [
  {
    "ExperienceId": 1,
    "ExperienceName": "TajMahel"
  },
  {
    "ExperienceId": 2,
    "ExperienceName": "AgraFort"
  }
   ]
  }
]
```

So I am writing a query like this but not working. I have no idea how to write nested queries.

```
var exp=from log in db.Places where(log.IsActive==true)
select new
{
    log.Id,
    from log1 in log.Experiences where(log1.LanguageId==1) select new {log1.Id,log1.Title}
};
```

Comment: I don't see definition about `IsActive`,`LanguageId` and `Title` . Are you sure you post the right parameter?

Comment: yes @Heinz Siahaan I have not posted complete table columns because they are so many. I just want to get an idea to fetch data in given format.

Comment: What is "not working"? Please give more details.

Comment: Pretty out of topic, but property Experience should be called Experiences. When trying to understand ERA model mapped to an object model it would a productivity killer to use inappropriate plural/singular

Comment: Its compile time error. It is not letting me write queries in this format. The error is- Invalid Anonymous type member declarator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this

```
     var exp = from log in db.Places
                      where log.IsActive==true
                      select new
                          {
                              logId= log.Id,,
                              experiences = from exp in log.Experiences 
                                         where(log1.LanguageId==1)
                                         select new
                                             {
                                                 id=log1.Id,
                                                 title=log1.Title
                                             }
                          };
```

[Anonymous Type Projection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15158465/entityframework-selectmany-with-anonymous-type-and-projection)

[Linq Projection](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/LinqProjection.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Eldho. I was exactly looking for this